# Como fazer para que o width seja o do texto e não da div

Tags: css

Quero que o background do H3 pegue somente o tamanho do texto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS

```
div.header {
    background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
div.header > h3 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 400%;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #222;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="header">
            <h3>TITLE</h3>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maneiras há varias, mas creio que para o seu CSS essa seja uma das mais simples:

- `display:inline-block;` no `h3` para que ocupe só o necessário;
- `text-align:center;` na `div` para que o `h3` fique centralizado.

Clique em executar e veja em funcionamento:

```css
div.header {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/chXVu.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    text-align:center;
}
div.header > h3 {
    margin: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 400%;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #222;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
</div>
```

<sub><sup>imagem vinda de http://www.wallpapers-for-desktop.eu</sup></sub>